# Why do Loan Discount Points Exist?

Tags: mortgage, loans

Loan Amount Disbursed = Face value of Mortgage in the contract *(1-discount points).

Why do we have this type of computation in place in the US? Is this conventional because of some history behind it?

Comment: Are you asking what discount points mean (e.g. what the net effect is) or the history behind the practice?

Comment: Both would be great. But the history is what I am primarily interested in or the motivation of it. I always thought of it as some sort of marketing tool such as $1.99 pre-tax for commercial transactions. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to the history of it - most likely some bank came up with the idea as a way to reduce a borrower's interest rate.

It is effectively "prepaid interest". You pay a "fee" upfront in exchange for a lower fixed interest rate. Whether this is beneficial to you as a borrower depends on how long you keep the mortgage (the longer you keep it, the more beneficial the lower interest rate is).

A "point" is 1% of your loan balance (the amount of interest you save is variable). So if you buy "2 points" to lower your interest rate, effectively you get 98% of your principal balance distributed. Alternatively, you could pay the points at closing instead of rolling them into the loan, but the net effect is the same.

For example, say you apply for a mortgage and the interest rate you are quoted is 3.5%. The bank may also offer a 0.25% "discount" for 1 point. So if you pay 1% of the balance upfront, then the interest rate on your mortgage will be 3.25% instead.  Using one of many discount points calculators available, you would need to keep this mortgage for **6 years** in order to make up for the upfront cost in interest savings.

Comment: How does getting less money reduce your interest rate?  ISTM that would *raise* your effective rate, since while 2% of 100 is (naturally) 2, 2 is 2.06% of 97.

Comment: @RonJohn The actual interest rate of your mortgage is decreased, usually more than offsetting the increase in loan balance. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks.  It would be useful, I think to see how much interest you'd pay if you just increased your original DP by 1%.

Comment: @RonJohn: A point affects present value directly.  To find the change in interest rate that gives the same effect, you'd need to know all the other variables in the present value of periodic payments equation (baseline interest rate, number of compounding intervals, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stanley. Is this a distinct concept from the down payment? The down payment is the minimum the borrower has to put down in order for the lender to enter into a risky lending contract, right? The way I try to think about your answer is when we plot the interest payment of, say, fixed mortgage over the life of the loan, say 30 years. Usually it starts of very high and slowly decreases and dives deep in the end years. So when you say, this is prepaid interest, does this shift this curve down? How do you know it shifts the earlier years down?

Comment: @DStanley What I am trying to say is that if the borrower of the loan who is using the loan discount point is to reap the benefit, you make the argument that this person has to still be in the contract for a certain amount of years; the price of having the effective interest lower for the mortgage is being locked in the contract for a certain amount, right, your argument? So this would mean when we plot the interest payment over lifetime of the loan, the curve would shit down disproportionately earlier years. How to prove such claim?

Comment: It is distinct from down payment. Down payment _reduces_ the principal and does not affect interest rate. You prove it by looking at each amortization schedule and graphing out the total interest paid to date for each period. At some point the interest savings will make up for the initial cost of lowering the interest rate. You know it shifts the earlier years down because the interest period is the interest rate times the principal balance. A lower interest rate means lower interest paid.